# Copy and rename files to a sequential numbering with subdirectories

Tags: shell-script, rename

I want to copy files of the given type with inside subdirectories.
I think copy of the zzz.txt file works after copying the files in the abc_folder.
How can i resolve this problem.

```
AAA
   ---aaa.txt
   ---bbb.txt
   ---zzz.txt
   ---abc_folder
                ---aaa.txt
                ---bbb.txt
                ---ccc.txt
```

Wanted output

```
    AAA
   ---aaa.txt
   ---bbb.txt
   ---zzz.txt
   ---1.txt
   ---2.txt
   ---3.txt
   ---abc_folder
                ---aaa.txt
                ---bbb.txt
                ---ccc.txt
                ---1.txt
                ---2.txt
                ---3.txt
```

My code's output

```
        AAA
   ---aaa.txt
   ---bbb.txt
   ---zzz.txt
   ---1.txt
   ---2.txt
   ---4.txt
   ---abc_folder
                ---aaa.txt
                ---bbb.txt
                ---ccc.txt
                ---1.txt
                ---2.txt
                ---3.txt
```

My code

```
#!/bin/bash

function traverse() {
counter=1
for file in "$2"/*
do
  if [ ! -d "${file}" ]; then
      if [[ $file == $3 ]]; then
          extension="${file##*.}"
          filename="${file%.*}"
          cp "$file" "${2}/${counter}.${extension}"
          counter=$(($counter + 1))
      fi
  elif [ $1 == "-R" ] ; then
      traverse "${1}" "${file}" "${3}"
  fi
done
}
traverse "$1" "$PWD" "$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
autoload zmv
incr='++count[$1]'
typeset -A count
zmv -n '(**/)(*)(.txt)' '$1$((incr))$3'
```

(remove `-n` when happy)

The idea being to use an associative arrays whose key is the directory for counting.

We need the intermediary `incr` variable or otherwise it wouldn't work for directory names containing `]`.

Comment: I want to use just pure bash